# Displaying two records from two different functions in oracle instead of in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, function, output, record

I wrote below function that works well. And displays the records

```
select emp_name,
       get_emp_status(emp_id) status_1,
       get_emp_name_dept(emp_id) status_2
from employee;
```

**Currently Output is**:

emp_name --------   status_1  ------   status_2

Claire  ----------------       Yes ------------           No

Taylor    ---------------     No  ---------------
Mikey ---------------         No---------------             Yes

However, I need the below results to be displayed. Please let me know how to proceed.

**Expected output needed:**

emp_name -----   Status

Claire   --------------Yes

Claire---------------No

Taylor --------------No

Mikey ---------------No

Mikey -------------- Yes

Comment: What is the status_2 of Taylor? Is it blank (or null)?

Comment: Yes. that's NULL for the status_2 of Taylor.

Answer (score 0):

Simple option is to `UNION` those results:

```
select emp_name,
       get_emp_status(emp_id) status
from employee
union all
select emp_name,
       get_emp_name_dept(emp_id) status
from employee
order by emp_name, status
```

Comment: Actually, my query already has couple of unions.... and then this one came as enhancement. Union could take longer time to execute my big query. Is there another option apart from Union?

Comment: UNION might slow things down as it returns distinct rows. UNION ALL (I suggested) doesn't do that, it just returns what it fetched